# iOS swift Collection View Cell bug conflicting with scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a collection view above a scrollview and when I scroll in the scroll view my cells are going in UIWindow hierarchy and I can scroll in the collection view any more because there are below scrollview. The collection view is a horizontal scroll and the scrollview is a vertical scroll. Really need help

Comment: why you are using scroll view in collection view as it has a default property of scroll..?

Comment: the collection view is not inside the scroll view is outside! I found the problem I am using CATransform3DIdentity and I need to find what parameter of this is moving my Z axis